# Replace div on scroll, abort scroll, jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am after a similar effect to that found here https://waaark.com/works/ - when you scroll down out of the top section, further scrolling actually replaces what is in view and no further scrolling happens. I don't want as complex animations though a simple slide in from the side is what I am after. that site is WordPress, but my site will not be.

I have tried to at least crack the slide in, but a lot of examples I have looked at and tried do not work, or don't work with multiple images - i.e. slide them all at once and don't wait for the scroll, and only slid in the first time you scroll down - want it to work every time you scroll up and down.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Fullpage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) - There are a few examples for different configurations and it is very easy to setup.